# Каким образом среда Visual Studio рассчитывает память для процесса?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, memory, struct

```
class stack
{
    struct unit
    {
        int value;
        unit *past;
    };
    unit *pointer = nullptr;
    int count = 0;
public:
    stack() {}
    ~stack()
    {
        unit *buf;
        while (pointer != nullptr)
        {
            buf = pointer;
            pointer = pointer->past;
            delete(buf);
        }
    }
    void Add(int value)
    {
        unit *buf = new unit;
        buf->value = value;
        buf->past = pointer;
        pointer = buf;
        count++;
    }
    int HowManySize() const
    {
        cout << "value - " << sizeof(int) << "\tpoint - " << sizeof(unit*) << "\tunit - " << sizeof(unit) << endl;
        return (sizeof(unit) * count) + sizeof(this);
    }
};
void main()
{
    stack obj;
    Sleep(2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        obj.Add(i);
    int w = obj.HowManySize();
    cout  << w / 1024 / 1024 << " Mbit\t" << ((float)w / 1024 /1024 /1024) << " Gbit";
    Sleep(2000);
    obj.~stack();
    Sleep(2000);
    return;
}
```

При вызове функции Add() 10 000 000 раз функция HowManySize() вернет значение которое будет равно примерно 152 мегабайтам. Однако средства диагностики Visual Studio покажет что было занято почти в шесть раз больше.

При запуске деструктора используемая память падает с 870 мегабайт до 500 килобайт, следовательно утечки памяти нет.

Вопрос почему потребляется так много памяти?

Потребление оперативной памяти в среде vs:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потребление вне среды:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, как минимум у вас есть накладные расходы - если вы выделяете 4 байта, это совсем не значит, что из свободной памяти откусывается именно это количество - есть еще и траты диспетчера памяти... Кроме того, если программа скомпилирована в отладочном режиме, то могут быть и другие траты - связанные с отладочным режимом, да, кстати, и с работой самой среды. Хотя - в 6 раз - это что-то запредельно много.

Comment: А никто не знает, что в результате скрывается за `T`. Может там хитрый класс, который динамические ещё себе памяти выделяет. И `sizeof` ее не поменяет.

Comment: @KoVadim Логично. Я почему-то решил, что это какой-то POD, но, собственно, и в самом деле - почему? :)

Comment: "функция HowManySize() вернет значение" - это в отладочной сборке? Может, студия еще и для профилировщика что-то выделяет...

Comment: Заменил шаблон на тип int результат тот же. Профилировщик в отладочной сборке выделяет, но непонятно сколько =/. Не могу придумать как измерить затраты памяти без среды vs. Может подскажите

Comment: Как насчёт [mcve]?

Comment: По идее, если перепишите на `new unit[10000000]`, будет меньше. Алокатор требует, наверное.

Comment: Проблема не в том как программно замерить, а в том сколько фактической памяти потребляется. По мнению Visual Studio в 6 раз больше замеренного оператором sizeof. Оставляю скрин: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Qhp/mXc5afWu1

Comment: Для начала нужно решить, а что такое "фактическая память"? если Вы у системы просите 4 байта, то скорее всего она даст Вам 4 килобайта (а то и больше). И что с этого считать "фактическим"?